# Why Does Python Allow *args After Keyword Arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example:

```
def foo(a, b=2, *args, **kwargs): pass
```

Why does this not result in a SyntaxError? *args will not catch additional non-keyword arguments because it is illegal to pass them after keyword arguments.

For python3.x the correct use of *args, **kwargs in this case looks like:

```
def foo(a, *args, b=2, **kwargs): pass
```

Thanks for any insights into this curious behavior.

Edit:

Thanks to Jab for pointing me to PEP 3102, which explains this behavior concisely. Check it out!

And also thanks to jsbueno for the additional excellent explanation, which I am updating as the best answer due to its thoroughness.

Comment: [PEP 0570](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/)

Comment: It is not allowed to **pass** them like that, but to **define** them like that.

Comment: You can call the function like this: `foo(1, 2, 3, c = 3, d = 4)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given:

```
def foo(a, b=2, *args, **kwargs): pass
```

`b` is not a keyword-only parameter - it is just a parameter for which arguments  can be positional or named, but have a default value. It is not possible to pass any value into `args` and omit passing `b` or passing `b` out of order in the signature you suggest.

This signature makes sense and is quite unambiguous - you can pass from 0 to n positional arguments, but if you pass 2 or more, the second argument is assigned to "b", and end of story.
If you pass 0 positional arguments, you can still assign values to "a" or "b" as named arguments, but trying anything like: `foo(0, 1, 2, a=3, b=4)` will fail as more than one value is attempted to be passed to both parameters.

Where as in:

```
def foo(a, *args, b=2, **kwargs): pass
```

it is also an unambiguous situation: the first positional argument goes to "a", the others go to "args", and you can only pass a value to "b" as a named argument.

The new  `/` syntax in signature definition coming with Python 3.8 gives more flexibility to this, allowing one to require that "a" and "b" are passed as positional-only arguments. Again, there is no ambiguity:

```
def foo(a, b=2, /, *args, **kwargs): pass
```

A curious thing on this new syntax: one is *allowed* to pass named arguments to "a" and "b", but the named arguments will come up as key/value pairs inside "kwargs" - while the local variables "a" and "b" will be assigned the positional only arguments:

```
def foo(a, b=2, /, *args, **kwargs): 
    print(a, b, args, kwargs)

...

In [9]: foo(1, 2, a=3, b=4)                                                                                                                                               
1 2 () {'a': 3, 'b': 4}
```

Whereas with the traditional syntax you ask about - `def foo(a, b=2, *args, **kwargs):` - one gets a TypeError if that is tried:

```
In [11]: foo(1,2, a=3, b=4)                                                                                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d002c7717dba> in <module>
----> 1 foo(1,2, a=3, b=4)

TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Answer (score 3):

This was implemented into 3.X for multiple reasons. Best way I can answer this is refer to
[PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Also take a look at the [New Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax) section in the Python 3.0.1 docs.

**TLDR:**

> Named parameters occurring after
> *args in the parameter list must be specified using keyword syntax in the call. You can also use a bare * in the parameter list to indicate
> that you don’t accept a variable-length argument list, but you do have
> keyword-only arguments.